# Chrome Web Apps and Google Apps Script

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script

I want to create a web app using Apps Script. Who gets charged for the quotas? The user installing the app or the developer?

Also, is it possible to pay for increased quotas?

Comment: Not a appengine question

Comment: Does it matter? Google moved their official forum to Stackoverflow. As far as I know, this is the only official place to ask questions like this.

If not, where would be an appropriate place?

Comment: You tagged your question with appengine. I removed the tag. You have to tag it with apps script!

Answer (score 1):

Whose quotas get used depends on how you deploy the app. When deploying you pick an option for "Execute the app as". The following is [from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps#deploying):

> **Execute the app as:** Do you want the web app to execute as you (the
>   owner of the script) or as the active user who is accessing the web
>   app?